# Не могу получить атрибут при парсинге SELENIUM

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Не могу получить атрибут при парсинге SELENIUM пытаюсь спарсить один сайт , но не могу понять как возможно получить атрибут.

ссылка на сайт = https://csgostats.gg/ru-RU/player/76561198316764924

не могу получить [image: Атрибут который не могу получить "33%"]

[image: атрибут]

пробовал через xpath , но выдает ошибку

код

```
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium_stealth import stealth
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()


ua = UserAgent()
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={ua.random}')

options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"C:\Users\boxer\Desktop\test\chroma_driver\chromedriver.exe")

stealth(driver,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win64",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
        )

url = "https://csgostats.gg/ru-RU/player/76561198343455039"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(7)


headshot = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="player-overview"]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]').text
print(headshot)


driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

всем заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте метод get.attribute по найденному элементу.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Метод XPATH находит этот селектор при парсинге этого сайта с использованием Selenium.
procent = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'(//div[@class='stat-panel'])[4]/div[2]/div[2])

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]